# Add current date to cURL request

Tags: batch-file, curl

I want to use cURL to automatically download files.
Tho, the files have the current date in their name and I would like to know how to automate the name to the current date if that makes sense! :)
Ex.:

```
@echo [off]
cd F:\Documents
f:
cURL https://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_hrdps/east/grib2/18/001/CMC_hrdps_east_TMP_TGL_120_ps2.5km_2020110418_P001-00.grib2 -o "HRDPS 18z TMP_TGL_120 f001.grib2"
pause
```

The **2020110418** in the file name would be today's date and I would like it to be automated

It is my first project with batch files. Hope it is clear and thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Have you searched this site? [How do I get current date/time on the Windows command line in a suitable format for usage in a file/folder name?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/203090)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now every modern windows machine has Powershell, so using Powershell with batch to get the date parts split (regarding regional settings):

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=_" %%i in ('powerShell -c "& {Get-Date -format "MM_dd_yyyy"}"') do (
    set MM=%%i
    set dd=%%j
    set yyyy=%%k
)
echo %yyyy%%mm%%dd%
```

Please tell what is 18, so it could be added like this

---

@Stephan nice, didn't thought this way:

```
for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%i in ('powerShell -c "& {Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"}"') do echo %%i
```

Comment: thank you! :)
But how can we copy the echo to the url?
18 is just the hour at which the weather model ran.

Comment: Ok I solved it!
I juste need to add the `%yyyy%%mm%%dd%` to the URL.
Like this:
`cURL https://dd.weather.gc.ca/model_hrdps/east/grib2/12/001/CMC_hrdps_east_TMP_TGL_2_ps2.5km_%yyyy%%mm%%dd%12_P001-00.grib2 -o HRDPS.12z.TMP_TGL_2.f001.grib2
`